# Java 8 : Iterate from 2 lists and create a Map<String, Custom Object>

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have a list of class A and class B with no duplicate elements. "code" attribute will be same across both class A and B. I want to convert them to  Map<String, C> using java 8 streams. Please help

```
public class A {
    private String code;
    private boolean status;
    field 3...
    field 4..

 
}

public class B {
    private String code;
    private String location;
    field 5...
    field 5..
}

public class C {
    private String location;
    private boolean status;
}

List1 : [A(code=NY, status=false), A(code=NJ, status=true),A(code=TX, status=true), A(code=NM, status=false)]

List2 : [B(code=NY, location=NewYork), B(code=NJ, location=NewJersey),B( code=TX, location=Texas), B(code=NM, location=NewMexico)]

Map =  map{NY=C(location=NewYork, status=false), NJ=C(location=NewJersey, status=true), TX=C(location=Texas, status=true),NM=C(location=NewMexico, status=false)}
```

Final map should be in the same order as the elements in List1

~A

UPDATE :
i updated the code to below, but its not compiling. any idea about whats wrong?

```
package test;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {

    static void main(String[] args){


        new Test().testFunction();

    }

      void testFunction(){


        System.out.println("Hello World");



        List<A> listA = Arrays.asList(new A("NY", false), new A("NJ", true), new A("TX", false), new A("AZ", true));
        List<B> listB = Arrays.asList(new B("NY", "New York"), new B("NJ", "New Jersey"),
                new B("TX", "Texas"), new B("NM", "New Mexico"));


        Map<String, B> mapB = listB
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(B::getCode, b -> b, (b1, b2) -> b1));

        Map<String, C> innerJoin = listA
                .stream()
                .filter(a -> mapB.containsKey(a.getCode())) // make sure a B instance exists with the code
                .map(a -> Map.entry(a.getCode(), new C(mapB.get(a.getCode()).getLocation(), a.getStatus())))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (c1, c2) -> c1, HashMap::new));

        innerJoin.forEach((code, c) -> System.out.println(code + " -> " + c));

    }

}


     class A {
        private String code;
        private boolean status;

         public A(String code, boolean status) {
             this.code = code;
             this.status = status;
         }
         public String getCode() {
             return this.code;
         }
         public boolean getStatus() {
             return this.status;
         }
     }

     class B {
        private String code;
        private String location;

         public B(String code, String location) {
             this.code = code;
             this.location = location;
         }

         public String getCode() {
             return this.code;
         }
         public String getLocation() {
             return this.location;
         }
     }

     class C {
        private String location;
        private boolean status;

         public C(String location, boolean status) {
             this.location = location;
             this.status = status;
         }
         public String getLocation() {
             return this.location;
         }
         public boolean getStatus() {
             return this.status;
         }
    }
```

Comment: share what you have tried so far so that others get to understand "how" to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You should use somethins like:

```
Map<String, B> mapList2 = list2.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(B::getCode, 
    Function.identity()); // create temporary map

Map<String,B> result = list1.stream().collect(
            LinkedHashMap::new,
            (map, a) -> map.put(
                   a.getCode(), // get code from A
                   new C(
                           mapList2.get(a.getCode()).getLocation() // get location from B
                           a.getStatus() // get status from A
                   ),  
             Map::putAll); // use LinkedHashMap to keep order
```

Comment: Agree that your solution is what OP exactly asked for. However it makes no sense for such a simple task to iterate 2 times when only 1 is needed and make a super complex code when it can be much easier and lighter. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos, do you mean one iteration seems is possible in case the lists are "sorted" by `code` property?

Comment: @Alex Rudenko check my answer

Comment: @Panagiotis Bougioukos, do you know that contains and get in List iterate all collection every time, so you solution iterate list1.size() * list2.size() * 2 instead of list1.size() + list2.size(). For example,  list1.size() = 1000, list2.size() = 1000, your solution has iteration 2 000 000 instead of 2000. Are you sure it is super complex code when it can be much easier and lighter? :)

Comment: Your points are right. I have not analyzed it so much when I wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

```java
Map<String, C> map = IntStream.range(0, list1.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> new CodeIndex(list1.get(i).code(), i))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        CodeIndex::code,
        ci -> new C(list2.get(ci.index()).location(), list1.get(ci.index()).status()),
        (a, b) -> a,
        LinkedHashMap::new
    ));
```

What happens is that we first get all valid indexes of both lists, then we map to a (custom) container class holding both the index and the code. (I called it `CodeIndex`, but you may as well use `Map.Entry` or some `Pair` class.)

At last, we collect it into a `LinkedHashMap` (because it retains insertion order), mapping the keys to simply `CodeIndex::code` and the values to `new C(«location_from_list2», «status_from_list1»)`.

Note that this code traverses the lists once.

Of course, this assumes that:

- both lists have the same codes;
- all codes of both `list1` and `list2` are in the same order.

---

*Note that I used record-style getters, that is, getters with the same name as their corresponding field names. For example, `location()` instead of `getLocation()`.*

Answer (score 1):

This task seems like to join two lists of objects by one key property.  Taking into account the requirements, it should be like inner join with the help of temporary map created from the `listB`.

```java
Map<String, B> mapB = listB
        .stream()
        .(Collectors.toMap(B::getCode, b -> b, (b1, b2) -> b1)); // use merge function as a defense measure

Map<String, C> innerJoin = listA
        .stream()
        .filter(a -> mapB.containsKey(a.getCode())) // make sure a B instance exists with the code
        .map(a -> Map.entry(a.getCode(), new C(mapB.get(a.getCode()).getLocation(), a.isStatus())))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (c1, c2) -> c1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Test:

```
List<A> listA = Arrays.asList(new A("NY", false), new A("NJ", true), new A("TX", false), new A("AZ", true));
List<B> listB = Arrays.asList(new B("NY", "New York"), new B("NJ", "New Jersey"), new B("TX", "Texas"), new B("NM", "New Mexico"));

// ...
innerJoin.forEach((code, c) -> System.out.println(code + " -> " + c));
```

Output:

```
NY -> C(location=New York, status=false)
NJ -> C(location=New Jersey, status=true)
TX -> C(location=Texas, status=false)
```

---

The "simplest" solution may be based on assumption that the items in both lists are "ordered" by the same `code` field, then no temporary map is needed:

```java
Map<String, C> simple = IntStream
        .range(0, listA.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> Map.entry(listA.get(i).getCode(), new C(listB.get(i).getLocation(), listA.get(i).isStatus())))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (c1, c2) -> c1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

However, such solution is too fragile.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use something like this to really maintain the order and group.

```
List<A> aList = Arrays.asList(new A("NY", false), new A("NJ", true));
List<B> bList = Arrays.asList(new B("NY", "NewYork"), new B("NJ", "NewJersey"));

LinkedHashMap<String, A> mapA =
        aList.stream().collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                        A::getCode,
                        a -> a,
                        (e1, e2) -> e1,
                        LinkedHashMap::new));

LinkedHashMap<String, B> mapB =
        bList.stream().collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                        B::getCode,
                        b -> b,
                        (e1, e2) -> e1,
                        LinkedHashMap::new));

Set<String> keys = new LinkedHashSet<>(mapA.keySet());
keys.addAll(mapB.keySet());

LinkedHashMap<String, C> result2 = keys.stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(
                key -> key,
                key -> new C(
                        mapB.get(key).getLocation(),
                        mapA.get(key).isStatus()),
                (e1, e2) -> e1,
                LinkedHashMap::new));
System.out.println(result2);
```